# how to set onItemClickListener() in a dialog listview?

Tags: android, listview, dialog, listadapter

In my app I have a dialog (dialog1), containing Listview with an ArrayAdapter having 3 string items. I want to set onItemclickListener() on this list,through which I would be able to start different activities on different item click. Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.new_service_request,LIST));

    ListView lv=getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, 
                int position, long id) {   
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        //  int ITEM_CLICKED = (int)getSelectedItemId();
            switch(position){
            case 0:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(New.this, Next.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(New.this, List.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent intent3= new Intent(New.this, HotCard.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                break;
```

Answer (score 3):

See if this helps

```
dialog1.setItems(array_of_items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //which is the item number in the list which you can use  
            //to do things accordingly
          }
        });
```

Comment: also implement OnItemClickListener in activity

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but, you could try within the dialog:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  //do stuff here

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a go at reproducing the example from http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html and then trying to adapt it to suit your purposes (i.e. in your dialog). I usually find it easier to get a grip on the problem in a simple use case before trying to shoe-horn it into my code. So in your `ListActivity`, you would call

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourThreeStringArray));
```

Then instead of the call to `Toast` in the example, simply start your activity something like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyIntent.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
```

(Replacing `MyIntent` with the class of your intended action, of course.)

Good luck!